# How to close template modals in handlebars?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, addeventlistener

I created an app that receives articles from news API. Each article is displayed in a card, which has a button "Open Modal".
This button opens a modal with the unique information that pertains to each respective article.

However, I am **unable to close the modal** once it's opened. I suspect it's because the modal is stuck in this state: `modals.forEach((modal, index) => {modal.classList.toggle('open', index === openIndex);`

Here is my current code:

```
 {{!-- #each article --}}
    <div class="row">
        {{#each articles}}
        
        <div class="col-12-sm col-6-md col-3-lg">
            <div class="card m-2">
                <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{title}}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{description}}</p>
                </div>
                <img class="card-image" src="{{urlToImage}}" alt="Card image cap">
                <button data-open-modal="{{@index}}">Open Modal</button>
                        
            </div>
        </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</div>


{{#each articles}}
 
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div class="modal closed" id="Modal_{{@index}}">
        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span id="spm" class="close" >&times;</span>
            <h2>{{title}}</h2>
            <img src="{{urlToImage}}" alt="">
            <p>{{content}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>

{{/each}}


<script>

    //Store all modals and modal buttons in variables
    const openModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-open-modal]');
    const modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

    //Loop through all modal buttons and assign handler to each
    openModalButtons.forEach(openModalButton => {
        openModalButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            //Get index value from number clicked
            const openIndex = Number(event.target.dataset.openModal); //Access dataset attribute to read and write
            
    //Loop over each modal. 
    //Set modal class to open if index is equal to wanted index
    modals.forEach((modal, index) => {
        modal.classList.toggle('open', index === openIndex);
        modal.classList.toggle('closed', index !== openIndex);
    });
  });
});

</script>
```

And here is what I tried adding to my script: (It gave no error but did nothing)

```
const span = document.querySelectorAll('.close');

let spanArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(span);
    
    spanArr.forEach(spanArr => {
        spanArr.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            const closeIndex = Number(event.target.dataset.closeModal); 

            spanArr[closeIndex].forEach(span => {
                span.onclick = function() {
                    modal.style.display = "none";
                }
            });  
        });
    });
```

I also tried adding event listeners to the spans, but I was unable to make it work. I am a beginner and this is my first time using handlebars, so thank you for any insight!

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73738690/3397771

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues here that perhaps are due to absent explanations on my part in https://stackoverflow.com/a/73738690/3397771.

First, the reason that `const openIndex = Number(event.target.dataset.openModal);` works is because there is a data-attribute called `data-open-modal` defined on each "open" button. It is that data-attribute that we are referencing with `dataset.openModal` and the value we will get back is the value on the right-hand-side of the equal sign in the attribute, the `{{@index}}` part.

However, the data-attribute approach is probably excessively complicated for our purposes here. We could, alternatively, use the `index` obtained in the `forEach` loop we use to iteratively add our click event listeners.

Next, there is no need for the `spanArr[closeIndex].forEach(...` loop inside our click handler. `spanArr` - despite its name - is not an arr(ay); it is a single `span` element.

The updated code becomes:

```
const span = document.querySelectorAll('.close');

span.forEach((spanArr, index) => { 
  spanArr.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modals[index].style.display = "none";
  });
});
```

Note: I have left the names of the variables as I found them, but they could and should be improved. For example, `span` does not communicate what purpose of these elements is or, for that matter, that it is a collection. `closeButtons` would be a better name. In fact, elements that behave like buttons should use the `<button>` element, not `<span>`, so as to be semantically correct and accessible.

I have created a new [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/bz79psn4/4/).

Comment: Thank you so much, I was going crazy! I appreciate it a lot, thanks for taking the time.

Comment: @JessicaDonley: You are welcome. If you were to make my answers as the accepted ones, it would be appreciated.